# HTML parsing by regular expression

Tags: html, regex, parsing

In my project, I have a form. Please see below:

[image]

here, I have two fields, HTMl and CSS. User can save their template by saving this form. Currently, I saved HTML and css as a separate field in my database. I need to prepare a template with valid data. So, I fetch the HTML from database. Please see the questions below:
*** When I fetch the HTML. It's a string.

1. I need to catch two numbers(1 and 5) from #{item(1, 5)} using regular expression. what will be the pattern?
2. I need to catch `<div class="layout">....</div>` block by using regular expression. What will be the pattern?
3. I need to replace #{url} with valid data by using regular expression. What will be the pattern?

Here is HTML with custom tag:

```
#{if(total,0)}#{else}
<div id="recommend">
  <div class="title"><p>Title</p></div>
    #{item(1,5)}
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#{url}"><img border="0" alt="#{name}" src="#{image}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="goods">
       <a href="#{url}">#{truncate(name,27)}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="price">#{comma(price_tax)}</div>
  </div>
  #{/item}
  <br clear="all">
</div>
#{/if}
```

Please help me.

Comment: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3000179)

Comment: [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Comment: @Khaled Saiful Islam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php you can follow this. It may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `#{[\w]+\((\d+),(\d+)\)}`

https://regex101.com/r/vS0uJ2/1

Output:

```
MATCH 1  
1.  [94-95] `1`  
2.  [96-97] `5`
```

2. `<div class="layout"\>((?:.*?(?:<div).*?(?:<\/div>).*?){0,})<\/div>`

https://regex101.com/r/bL8gY3/2

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [102-371]   
`<div class="layout">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#{url}"><img border="0" alt="#{name}" src="#{image}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="goods">
       <a href="#{url}">#{truncate(name,27)}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="price">#{comma(price_tax)}</div>
  </div>`
```

3. `<a href="(#\{url\})`

https://regex101.com/r/aB2sH1/1

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [161-167]   `#{url}`
MATCH 2
1.  [270-276]   `#{url}`
```

Comment: Regarding answer of Q2, I have checked your link. Its working but when I used it in my code, it didn't work. Other answers are working.

Comment: Would you please tell me, If I want to catch #{image} and #{name}, what will be the pattern?